# jQuery font size wrong result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to write a script to help disabled people to read the site. On a button click, I'd like to increase all font-size in my page. However the script sets wrong values. The code is the following:

```
$('main *').each((index, item) => {
    let current = parseInt($(item).css('font-size'));
    let increased = current * 1.2;

    $(item).css({
        fontSize: increased + 'px'
    });

})
```

However, it give me back totally wrong increased number. For example when the current font size was 14px sometimes it gives back 26px or 32px or 38px; The current value is get by the css() function, so it doesn't depend on the css file, it gets the computed value. When I try to log the current and increased value, it is fine. Something goes wrong, when I try to set it to the element.

Comment: Increase font size on the body.... have css be based off that size. TADA. No reason to update every element.

Comment: `console.log($(item).css('font-size'))` Is it what you expect? Are all the fonts px? Hard to help without seeing html/css. But that code will select parent and every child element.... So with `<div><span><i></i></span></div>` you will update div, span, i.

Comment: @epascarello the problem is that I didn't wrote the code and there are many elements whose font size is explicitly given in the css. So basically, I have to go through all the elements, get its size, and resize it to the given size

Comment: Also, you can try running this code in your console on this page. The fonts will be ridiculously big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is flawed because your code is going to adjust every element that is nested since you are using `*` as a selector. Below is a simple example showing how nesting will cause each layer to increase.

```js
$('.main *').each((index, item) => {
    let current = parseInt($(item).css('font-size'));
    let increased = current * 1.2;

    $(item).css({
        fontSize: increased + 'px'
    });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <p>One</p>
  <div>
    <p>Two</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Four</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Five</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So the code selects the element and increases the size. It selects the child, increases it size, selects that child's child and the next child..... So you are blowing up quickly.

So for your solution it would have to be somehow more restrictive on what you would update. Without knowing the html/css it is hard to know how things have font sizes applied. You would have to do something that would say X element has a font applied. That is not really the best idea.

A bad solution is to set a hardCoded value on every element.

```js
$('.main *').css('font-size', function () { return $(this).css('font-size') });


$("button").on("click", function() {
  $('.main *').each((index, item) => {
    let current = parseInt($(item).css('font-size'));
    let increased = current * 1.2;

    $(item).css({
      fontSize: increased + 'px'
    });

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Bigger</button>
<div class="main">
  <p>One</p>
  <div>
    <p>Two</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Four</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Five</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

A typical solution for this is using REM in CSS so all the values will increase based off a size you set on the html root.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  const html = $('html');
  const current = parseInt(html.css('font-size'));
  const increased = current * 1.2;
  html.css({
    fontSize: increased + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
#one { font-size: 1.5rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>bigger</button>
<div class="main">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p id="one">One (styled)</p>
  <div>
    <p>Two</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Four</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Five</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yeah I know it is hard to to help, without seeing the code, so thanks for trying. The problem is that many elements size is hardcoded in pixels, so for example 8px. The nesting wouldn't be a problem, since jquery's css() function sets an inline style, and it overrides the external style. Also when I go throught the element, in the beginnig and log the current and the increased size, the values are correct. So for example, the current is 12px and the increased is 14,4. But the problem is with the setting. The code doesnt set 14,4 despite the variable value is 14,4 but a totally different number

Comment: Yes it would be a problem. The above shows it. If the 8px element has children elements, they will still increase. Only way it would not fail is if you set a size on every single element.....

Comment: I added a solution in the middle.